# Button handlers not working. Basic Java rectangle calculator

Tags: java

So I have been following a tutorial for a basic Java GUI calculator. For whatever reason, when I go to click the Calculate button, the console gives a huge list of errors. How can I fix this.

Code:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class RectangleProgram extends JFrame {

private static final int WIDTH = 400;
private static final int HEIGHT = 300;

private JLabel lengthL, widthL, areaL;
private JTextField lengthTF, widthTF, areaTF;
private JButton calculateB, exitB;

//Button handlers
private CalculateButtonHandler cbHandler;
private ExitButtonHandler ebHandler;

public RectangleProgram(){
    lengthL = new JLabel("Enter the length: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    widthL = new JLabel("Enter the width: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    areaL = new JLabel("Area: ", SwingConstants.RIGHT);

    lengthTF = new JTextField(10);
    widthTF = new JTextField(10);
    areaTF = new JTextField(10);


    //New buttons

    calculateB = new JButton("Calculate");
    cbHandler = new CalculateButtonHandler();
    calculateB.addActionListener(cbHandler);
    exitB = new JButton("Exit");
    ebHandler = new ExitButtonHandler();
    exitB.addActionListener(ebHandler);

    setTitle("Sample Title: Area of a rectangle");
    Container pane = getContentPane();
    pane.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 2));

    //Adding wings and things... well just things... no wings :(

    pane.add(lengthL);
    pane.add(lengthTF);
    pane.add(widthL);
    pane.add(widthTF);
    pane.add(areaL);
    pane.add(areaTF);
    pane.add(calculateB);
    pane.add(exitB);

    setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    setVisible(true);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

}


private class CalculateButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(Action e){
        double width, length, area;

        length = Double.parseDouble(lengthTF.getText());
        width = Double.parseDouble(widthTF.getText());
        area = length * width;

        areaTF.setText("" + area);
    }
}

public class ExitButtonHandler implements ActionListener{

    public void actionPerformed(Action e){
        System.exit(0);

    }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    RectangleProgram rectObj = new RectangleProgram();
}
```

}

Errors:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation >problem: 
>     The type RectangleProgram.CalculateButtonHandler must implement the >inherited abstract method ActionListener.actionPerformed(ActionEvent)
>
> at >RectangleProgram$CalculateButtonHandler.actionPerformed(RectangleProgram.java:5>9)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at >java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(U>nknown Source)
>     at >java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(U>nknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
>     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>     at >java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(U>nknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
>     at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)

Comment: Please post code and errors *here*.

Comment: Put an annotation of @Override on the actionPerformed and make sure it has the same signature and parameters as the abstract method

Comment: @AndrewL. I added an Override and it did nothing to the program

Comment: I said have the same signature and parameters as the superclass's abstract method. You didn't do that. You had to put the same parameters as pointed out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your actionPerformed methods, change your parameter from "Action e" to "ActionEvent e" in both your CalculateButtonHandler and ExitButtonHandle class.

If you take a look at the [ActionListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html) interface method detail, you will notice that the method actionPerformed take an ActionEvent as a parameter. Since you are implementing the interface in your classes, you are required to override the method as such.

Comment: I'm rather new to Java. Can you explain why this change needed to be made?

Comment: You have to have the same parameters as the superclass method to correctly override the method in a subclass. You didn't have the same parameters so the method didn't do it's job.